# How to set Mailersend PHP API - template variables?

Tags: php, email

I've been trying to use Mailersend's PHP API for sending a template, but can't properly  set template vars. :

Code is:

```
...
$mailersend = new MailerSend(['api_key' => $maSecretKey]);
$recipients = [
    new Recipient('client_email@gmail.com', 'the email'),
];
$variables = [
    new Variable('my_registered_email@mail.com', ['date' => date('Y-m-d'), 'order_number'=>250, 'delivery'=>"chosen"])
];

$tags = ['tag'];

$emailParams = (new EmailParams())
    ->setFrom('my_registered_email@mail.com')
    ->setFromName('Website')
    ->setRecipients($recipients)
    ->setSubject('Se registro un pago nuevo')
    ->setTemplateId($templateVenta)
    ->setVariables($variables);
    //->setTags($tags);

$mailersend->email->send($emailParams);
```

Result:

> [22-Jun-2023 07:38:51 America/Chicago] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught MailerSend\Exceptions\MailerSendValidationException: The variables.0.email field does not exist in to.*.email. (and 1 more error) in /home4/distrib2/public_html/tt/correo/vendor/mailersend/mailersend/src/Helpers/HttpErrorHelper.php:27

Documentation is at: https://github.com/mailersend/mailersend-php#setup

Comment: yes because Instead of creating a new `Variable` object, you must pass the variables directly as an associative array!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never used this library, but looking quickly at the documentation I think I can see the problem.

It's not explicitly stated in the docs, at least from a brief glance, but in all the examples using Variables (such as https://github.com/mailersend/mailersend-php#send-a-template-based-email), the first parameter in the `Variable` constructor uses an email address which is also specified as a `Recipient`.

I assume this is so that it can use those variable values to substitute into templated emails to that recipient...it seems logical.

But in the code in your question, you have two different email addresses in these fields. The error message is obscurely worded, but it seems to be complaining that the email you've used in the Variable doesn't match any addresses in the Recipients list. "I can't apply these variables to a non-existent recipient", it seems to be saying.

https://developers.mailersend.com/api/v1/features.html#simple-personalization appears to back this up, saying:

> A simple personalization allows you to print basic data using variables in {$var} format for each recipient when sending emails

So clearly a set of variables must be associated with a valid recipient, otherwise they have no viable destination.

Also, the example at https://github.com/mailersend/mailersend-php#debugging-validation-errors shows a mismatch between these two fields as an example of how to generate a validation error, in order to see how to debug them.

Taking all this into account, I am 99% certain this is the root of your problem.

Therefore I expect that

```
$recipients = [
    new Recipient('client_email@gmail.com', 'the email'),
];
$variables = [
    new Variable('client_email@gmail.com', ['date' => date('Y-m-d'), 'order_number'=>'250', 'delivery'=>"chosen"])
];
```

is likely to resolve the error in this case.

You also need to ensure all the variable values are strings (rather than any other data type) so I've changed the order_number to '250' instead of 250.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately still not working. It puzzles me as new error is: Uncaught MailerSend\Exceptions\MailerSendValidationException: The variables.0.substitutions.1.value must be a string.

Comment: I'd guess that means that the value for order_number must be a string rather than an int. `variables.0.substitutions.1` would seem to point to the index of the order_number parameter in your variable array, and that value is, indeed, not a string.

Comment: Great. I've adjusted the answer to reflect that as well. It's well worth paying close attention to examples, and to the content of error messages in these cases :-)

Comment: Indeed! Best regards.